# Unable to seek HTML5 video in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, video-streaming, html5-video, http-status-codes

I have two projects that plays mp4 video

1. pure html (static html files)
2. Spring MVC application.
   Both of above projects are deployed in Tomcat 8.

When I access the html project using below URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/videoplayer/index.html
```

**The page opens and plays the mp4 video. also, I am able to seek video forward/backward.**

I have added same content of above index.html page into spring mvc jsp.
When I access that index.jsp,

**The page opens and plays the video.
However, I am not able to seek forward/backward. Also, clicking on video seek bar starts the video from beginning**

**Note: In Spring MVC, I have added the video as resource.**

below is the resource configuration:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/vids/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/vids/");
    }
```

**Controller method:**

Below method is used to serve the page that has video :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/play", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String playvideo() {
            return "index";
    }
```

However, even if I directly hit the video resource url in browser I'm not able to seek through video.

```
http://localhost:8080/tkh/resources/vids/cars.mp4
```

When i check the request and the headers in both the application, chrome shows below:

**1. HTML project**

**For html project the http status code is 206**

[image]

**2. Spring MVC project**

**For spring project the http status code is 200**

[image]

Below is the html/jsp code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>title</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/media/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/media/style.css" media="screen">

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body { background: #f2f2f2 ; padding-top: 265px; }
        .mejs-container { margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
</head>

<body>

    <video width="640" height="267"  controls="controls" autobuffer="true" poster="resources/vids/cars.png">
        <source src="resources/vids/cars.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('video, audio').mediaelementplayer();
        $('video').mediaelementplayer({
            alwaysShowControls: true,
            videoVolume: 'horizontal',
            features: ['playpause','progress','volume','fullscreen']
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I understand 206 status code is for partial content. But then why spring mvc application sends 200 status instead of 206?

I'm really not sure why the page having same code is behaving this way?

Comment: 206 status is perfectly normal because your player is requesting the media with a given byte range (header Range: bytes=2161242-). So your server respond with 206. When you access your media directly the request doesn't contains a range.

Comment: But MVC application gives 200 status. And I'm not accessing directly.

Comment: What do you mean by MVC application ?

Comment: I'm mean its a Spring mvc application where I'm getting response as 200 for request url in above image #2

Comment: What do you mean by "html project" (serving static files with an http server?). Which Spring version are you using? How are you serving that mp4 file (Spring resource handling? a Controller? a default servlet in your application?). Show us some server code :-)

Comment: 'html project' means only static html pages. I'm using spring 4.1.6. Video it is served using resource handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the seek issue by upgrading to Spring 4.2.5.